# How to stop Terlerik RadEditor from de-obfuscates email addresses

Tags: telerik, radeditor

I am running into an issue where if you put an obfuscated email address in the RadEditor it de-obfuscates it.

You put the following in:

```
<a href='&#109;&#97;ilto&#58;John&#46;Doe%4&#48;%65x&#37;61%&#54;Dple&#46;com'>&#74;&#111;&#104;n&#46;D&#111;&#101;&#64;exa&#109;ple&#46;&#99;o&#109;</a>
```

It converts it to:

```
<a href="mailto:John.Doe%40%65x%61%6Dple.com">John.Doe@example.com</a>
```

How do you stop the control from doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the browser that does that (read the HTML entities and transform them): https://jsfiddle.net/x1wxpaps/ so I doubt you can stop it.

```
<div style="border: 2px solid red; width: 300px; height: 300px;" contentEditable="true" id="test">
<a href='&#109;&#97;ilto&#58;John&#46;Doe%4&#48;%65x&#37;61%&#54;Dple&#46;com'>&#74;&#111;&#104;n&#46;D&#111;&#101;&#64;exa&#109;ple&#46;&#99;o&#109;</a>
</div>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML)
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, I believe it is the control... If you go into code view and paste the mailto url it looks ok.  Switch to html view and then switch back to code view the url is de-obfuscated.

Comment: The HTML mode is a <textarea> element, the design mode is an editable <iframe> element. This is why the example I showed you above uses an editable element - the rich text engine of the browser kicks in there and often changes HTML as soon as you place it there. RadEditor puts the HTML string you provide in the editable element with JavaScript, but this does not really make a difference in this case.

Comment: I am giving you credit for the correct answer to my question.  Thanks for the explanation.  I now must come up with a clever hack to work around this.  Maybe a little regex to detect email addresses and obfuscate it as I store the data in the database.  Thank you very much.